# Prove that if we add the edge $(u,v)$ to $T$, the resulting graph has exactly one cycle.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $T$ be a tree with $u,v\in V (T)$, $u$ is not equal to $v$, and $(u,v)$ does not belong to $E(T)$. Prove that if we add the edge $(u,v)$ to $T$, the resulting graph has exactly one cycle.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I can't prove it. I can see it on examples, but I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: What do you know about trees?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inductively on the number of leaves of the tree. Base case: two leaves, which is easy because a tree with two leaves is just a line, and adding a single edge to a line either turns the whole thing into a loop or it adds a single loop somewhere inside the line.

- If $u$ and $v$ are both not leaves, then remove a leaf and you're done by induction.
- If exactly one of $u$ and $v$ is a leaf, then there's another leaf which you can remove and be done by induction again.
- Otherwise, both are leaves; either there is a third leaf (in which case done by induction when you remove it) or there's no third leaf (base case).

Note that the inductive step of removing a leaf can't possibly remove any cycles, because a leaf can't be part of a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Let *n* be the number of vertices, *e* be the number of edges and *f* be the number of faces. If T is a tree, then we have

$$n = e + 1$$

and since every tree can be represented as a planar graph, Euler's characteristic equation holds, that is,

$$n - e + f = 2$$

which gives f = 1, obviously. Let *T* ' be the new graph after adding one more edge to *T* and *n*', *e*', *f* ' be the number of vertices, edges and faces of *T* ' respectively, with

$$n' = n$$ $$ e' = e + 1$$

Now, without loss of generality, you can add this edge without breaking the planarity (since *T* has no cycles) so that Euler's characteristic equation still holds for *T* ':

$$n' - e' + f ' = 2$$

Since you have now *n' = e'*, *f '* must be 2. Therefore there is exactly one cycle in the new graph *T '* (One face is inside of cycle and one face is outside of cycle).